# python setup.py install does not work with latest setuptools: no scripts in '<*>.egg-info'

Tags: python, setuptools

Using setuptools==27.2.0, the travis tests of our package picca (https://github.com/igmhub/picca) works well. It is no longer the case using the latest version of setuptools==41.0.0: https://github.com/igmhub/picca/issues/591 .

The issue seems to be linked to where setuptools tries to read the scripts.
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/bin/picca_deltas.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('picca==4.0', 'picca_deltas.py')
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1437, in run_script
    .format(**locals()),
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/picca_deltas.py' not found in metadata at '/home/travis/build/igmhub/picca/py/picca.egg-info'
```

When looking to the path `/home/travis/build/igmhub/picca/py/picca.egg-info/` indeed there are no `scripts` folder.
Our python setup is the following, is there something we should change so that setup tools know where to find the scripts?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob

from setuptools import setup

scripts = glob.glob('bin/*')

description = "Package for Igm Cosmological-Correlations Analyses"

version="4.0"
setup(name="picca",
    version=version,
    description=description,
    url="https://github.com/igmhub/picca",
    author="<***>",
    author_email="<***>",
    packages=['picca','picca.fitter2'],
    package_dir = {'': 'py'},
    package_data = {'picca': ['fitter2/models/*/*.fits']},
    install_requires=['numpy','scipy','iminuit','healpy','fitsio',
        'llvmlite','numba','h5py','future','setuptools'],
    test_suite='picca.test.test_cor',
    scripts = scripts
)
```

The command `/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/bin/picca_deltas.py` looks like the following on my computer:

```
#!<where is python>/python/3.6.3/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'picca==4.0','picca_deltas.py'
__requires__ = 'picca==4.0'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('picca==4.0', 'picca_deltas.py')
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild shot, but I just had the same issue.

Look at how `/home/travis/build/igmhub/picca/py/picca.egg-info` looks like your build folder. It shouldn't be looking into the egg-info in the build folder, but the one you installed.

Just change directory and you should be fine:

```
cd .. # or cd anywhere outside your build folder
picca_deltas.py
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure to understand. All of these is used primarily, for us, for travis to run automatic tests. Thus I can not do `cd ..`. Or can I? Maybe I did not understand at all you fix. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I didn't realize you were getting into this with a call to `python setup.py test`...

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, I now run the test using `pytest` instead of `python setup.py test`.
https://github.com/igmhub/picca/pull/698/files.
The clue was in the following message;

```
WARNING: Testing via this command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Users looking for a generic test entry point independent of test runner are encouraged to use tox.
```